# Eclipse plugin: update view following a command

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin where I execute a command triggered from a toolbar icon. After the command completes I want to update a view which will display a table containing data collected while executing the command.

My issue is that I don't know how to listen to the command completion from the view.

I have checked the below which concern other view selection changes but no command execution:

[How to Refresh Eclipse View Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352718/how-to-refresh-eclipse-view-plugin)

https://eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html

Comment: Well what are you doing in the command handler?

Comment: Inside the method public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) I scan a C source AST and collecting some metrics (for example line of code) which are supposed to be displayed in the view. The data is collected in a map data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the currently active part in your handler class and check if it is your view. If it is you can call a method you define on the view. Something like:

```java
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

  IWorkbenchPart part = HandlerUtil.getActivePart(event);

  if (part instanceof MyView) {

    MyView view = (MyView)part;

    // Call some method of your view
    view.someMethodOfMyView(....);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - the idea worked by I've modified it a little bit: HandlerUtil.getActivePart will return my view only if it is focused so in order to get my view I'm using IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(MyView.ID);